# CSS cropping div elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery wizard plugin called [jQuery-Steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/). Problem is that for some reason div elements inside my forms are cropped. i.e. right side is missing. When I remove jQuery plugin input type boxes are correctly shown:

Here is picture of result:

[image: Result that I have]

jsFiddle link:

[Click me](http://jsfiddle.net/4A6Wj/)

CSS that I am using for plugin:

```
/*
    Common 
*/

.wizard,
.tabcontrol
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.wizard a,
.tabcontrol a
{
    outline: 0;
}

.wizard ul,
.tabcontrol ul
{
    list-style: none !important;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.wizard ul > li,
.tabcontrol ul > li
{
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Accessibility */
.wizard > .steps .current-info,
.tabcontrol > .steps .current-info
{
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
    display: none;
}

.wizard > .content > .title,
.tabcontrol > .content > .title
{
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
}



/*
    Wizard
*/

.wizard > .steps
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.wizard.vertical > .steps
{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}

.wizard > .steps .number
{
    font-size: 1.429em;
}

.wizard > .steps > ul > li
{
    width: 25%;
}

.wizard > .steps > ul > li,
.wizard > .actions > ul > li
{
    float: left;
}

.wizard.vertical > .steps > ul > li
{
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.wizard > .steps a,
.wizard > .steps a:hover,
.wizard > .steps a:active
{
    display: none;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 0.5em 0.5em;
    padding: 1em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.wizard > .steps .disabled a,
.wizard > .steps .disabled a:hover,
.wizard > .steps .disabled a:active
{
    background: #eee;
    color: #aaa;
    cursor: default;
}

.wizard > .steps .current a,
.wizard > .steps .current a:hover,
.wizard > .steps .current a:active
{
    background: #2184be;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: default;
}

.wizard > .steps .done a,
.wizard > .steps .done a:hover,
.wizard > .steps .done a:active
{
    background: #9dc8e2;
    color: #fff;
}

.wizard > .steps .error a,
.wizard > .steps .error a:hover,
.wizard > .steps .error a:active
{
    background: #ff3111;
    color: #fff;
}

.wizard > .content
{
  /*  background: #eee;*/
    display: block;
   /* margin: 0.5em;*/
  /*  min-height: 35em;*/
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
/*
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;*/
}

.wizard.vertical > .content
{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 2.5% 0.5em 2.5%;
    width: 65%;
}

.wizard > .content > .body
{
    float: left;
  /*  position: absolute;*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  /*  padding: 2.5%;*/
}

.wizard > .content > .body ul
{
    list-style: disc !important;
}

.wizard > .content > .body ul > li
{
    display: list-item;
}

.wizard > .content > .body > iframe
{
    border: 0 none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.wizard > .content > .body input
{
    display: block;
   /* border: 1px solid #ccc;*/
}



.wizard > .content > .body label
{
    display: inline-block;
  /*  margin-bottom: 0.5em;*/
}

.wizard > .content > .body label.error
{
    color: #8a1f11;
    display: inline-block;
    /*margin-left: 1.5em;*/
}

.wizard > .actions
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
}

.wizard.vertical > .actions
{
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 2.5%;
    width: 95%;
}

.wizard > .actions > ul
{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
}

.wizard > .actions > ul > li
{
    margin: 0 0.5em;
}

.wizard.vertical > .actions > ul > li
{
    margin: 0 0 0 1em;
}

.wizard > .actions a,
.wizard > .actions a:hover,
.wizard > .actions a:active
{
    background: #4493d9;
    font-family: "Lato";
    font-size: 13pt;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.wizard > .actions .disabled a,
.wizard > .actions .disabled a:hover,
.wizard > .actions .disabled a:active
{
    background: #eee;
    color: #aaa;
}

.wizard > .loading
{
}

.wizard > .loading .spinner
{
}



/*
    Tabcontrol
*/

.tabcontrol > .steps
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.tabcontrol > .steps > ul
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 6px 0 0 0;
    top: 1px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.tabcontrol > .steps > ul > li
{
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 2px 0 0;
    padding: 1px;

    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.tabcontrol > .steps > ul > li:hover
{
    background: #edecec;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    padding: 0;
}

.tabcontrol > .steps > ul > li.current
{
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    border-bottom: 0 none;
    padding: 0 0 1px 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.tabcontrol > .steps > ul > li > a
{
    color: #5f5f5f;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 0 none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.tabcontrol > .steps > ul > li > a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.tabcontrol > .steps > ul > li.current > a
{
    padding: 15px 30px 10px 30px;
}

.tabcontrol > .content
{
   /* position: relative;*/
    display: inline-block;
   /* width: 100%;
    height: 35em;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
    padding-top: 20px;*/
}

.tabcontrol > .content > .body
{
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    width: 95%;
    height: 95%;
    padding: 2.5%;
}

.tabcontrol > .content > .body ul
{
    list-style: disc !important;
}

.tabcontrol > .content > .body ul > li
{
    display: list-item;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with your CSS. The `width: 90%` value added to the `padding` value of that input causes it to be bigger than the container it is in. If you add the following to your css it should fix it:

```
#datepicker {
  width: 87% !important;
  padding-left: 8% !important;
  padding-right: 4.5% !important;
}

#table {
  width: 100% !important;   
}

#aligned {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Fixed jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4A6Wj/3/